# Multidimensional Array merged to single line array

Tags: php

I am working with an array that sometimes has a multidimensional array. I am trying to accomplish making this array into a single line array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute_code] => 203
            [attribute_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 24214
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [attribute_code] => 252
            [attribute_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 22865
                    [1] => 25086
                )

        )

)
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"attribute_code":"203","attribute_value":"24214"}
    [1] => {"attribute_code":"252","attribute_value":["22865","25086"]}
)
```

What would the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just JSON encoding each element:

```
$result = array_map("json_encode", $array);
```

Comment: You could reduce this to `$result = array_map("json_encode", $array);`

Comment: @NigelRen:  Thanks, it's been an overthinking stuff kind of day ;-)